# How to convert a year string into a date in PHP?

Tags: php, date

I am trying to convert a string into a date. Specifically, a string of a year into a date.

```
strtotime('2017') // Gives us -> 1517372220

$year = '2017';
var_dump($year); // '2017'
$year = date("Y", strtotime($year));
var_dump($year); // '2018'
```

Why is the date method defaulting to the current time? I am passing an integer.

According to the documentation, I seem to implementing this method correctly?

> string date ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )
>
> The optional timestamp parameter is an integer Unix timestamp that
>   defaults to the current local time if a timestamp is not given. In
>   other words, it defaults to the value of time().

Comment: strtotime() always returns seconds since Unix Epoch w/o time zone information, i.e. in UTC time zone. date() on the other hand will represent timestamps in the system default time zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [strtotime() Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

strtotime — Parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp

> Parameters
>
> **time**-> ***A date/time string***. Valid formats are explained in ***Date and Time*** Formats.

So either you need to provide a textual representation or a valid date format (not only years).

So code need to be like this:-

```
<?php

$year = date("Y", strtotime('2017-01-01'));
var_dump($year); // '2018'
```

Output:- https://eval.in/945561

Reference:- [valid formats for strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php)

Comment: Ah..Thanks for that reference link. Makes sense, I got it.

Comment: @calbear47  glad to help you :):)